# Write the polynomial equation given information about a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus

With the following information, I am to write the equation of the polynomial:

Degree 3, zeros at $x=-2$, $x=1$, $x=3$, y intercept: $0,-4$

I know that the answer is: $f(x)=\frac{-2}{3}(x+2)(x-1)(x-3)$

If you look at my post history you can see that I nearly always show what I've tried and where I've gotten stuck. In this case, I do not know where to start or how to approach this problem.

How can one take the given information and calculate the polynomial? Granular, baby steps preferred.

Comment: Do you understand why the factors $x + 2, x - 1, x - 3$ arise?

Comment: given the solution, the intercept should be $-4$

Comment: The linear factors follow directly from the zeros. You know $f(0)=4.$ The constant multiplier should be $2/3$ or $f(0)$ should be $-4.$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I understand that they are the points where a smooth continuis polynomial function cross the x axis, each time corresponding to one of the factors with the local behavior of that factor e.g. straight intercept (degree 1), bounce (even degree) or a squiggle (odd degree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know some zeroes of a polynomial, say $a$, $b$ and $c$, you can write
$$
P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)Q(x)
$$
where $Q(x)$ is a new polynomial, in fact, if you substitute, for example, $a$, you get
$$
P(a)=(a-a)(b-a)(c-a)Q(a)=0\cdot(b-a)(c-a)Q(a)=0
$$
and the same happens if you substitute $b$ or $c$.

If you know the degree of the polynomial $P$, then you can foresee the degree of the polynomial $Q$, in fact 3 degree are already taken from $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, so the degree of $Q$ is three unit lesser than the degree of $P$.

In the present case $P$ is known to have degree $3$, so $Q$ should have degree $0$, i.e. it is a constant polynomial, i.e. you have
$$
P(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)k
$$
You can obtain $k$ applying the remaining request, that the intercept is $y_0$,
$$
P(0)=y_0\quad\implies\quad(-a)(-b)(-c)k=y_0\quad\implies\quad k=-\frac{y_0}{abc}
$$
(obviously this is true if all of $a,b,c$ are different from $0$).